# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Angela Lu course

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

I'm getting this error while trying to stream data from firebase cloud
I don't know what to do

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final messages = snapshot.data?.docs;

                  for (var message in messages!) {
                    final messageData = message.data();
                    final messageText = messageData['text'];
                    final messageSender = messageData['sender'];
                    final messageWidget =
                        Text('$messageSender said $messageText');
                    messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                  }
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
              },
            ),
```

the error in those two lines

```
 final messageText = messageData['text'];
 final messageSender = messageData['sender'];
```

trying to get and stream data from firbase cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as` prefix to object to Map. Then you can use keys to get the data.

```dart
final messageData = message.data() as Map?;
final messageText = messageData?['text']??"default msg";
final messageSender = messageData?['sender']??"default sender";
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer for me to know what is really goind in the code?

Comment: firstly, we are casting Object to Map., then reading the value. Also I've accepted nullable(Map?) , if the map is null or data reading key provide null, it will return default  value(`??` right part). More about [get-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)